# How to mute or reduce the volume of IMA ads?

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-dfp

For some days I've been working on google's IMA (or DFP).

Now I need to know how to mute them even when it is loaded. I searched for that. Can't find a proper solution.

**Note:**

I didn't use any video player. Because I am adding it before a game loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setVolume right after you started your adsmanager instance (see [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/reference/js/google.ima.AdsManager#setVolume) for details) :

```
adsmanager.start();
//0 to mute, 1 to unmute
adsManager.setVolume(0);
```

Comment: Worked thanks! please check my profile. I have more question on IMA. I think you can solve them :)